# How to read from file into a vector of class objects?

Tags: c++, file-io, vector

I need to be able to save a vector of class objects, which I am able to do; however, I can not figure out how to read back in the data. I have tried all of the things that i know how to do and some of the things i have seen on here, none of it has helped me.

I have created a test class and main to figure out a way to read in the data. The latest attempt i was able to get the first object into the program but the rest don't. This is a test to see if i can get it to work before I implement it into my homework, that have multiple data members

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class typeA
{
    string name; //the name is multiple words
    int id;
public:
    typeA(string name, int id): name(name), id(id){}
    typeA(){}

    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const typeA& a)
    {
        out << a.name << '\n';
        out << a.id << '\n';
        return out;
    }

    friend istream& operator >>(istream& in, typeA& a)
    {
        getline(in, a.name); // since the name is first and last i have to use getline
        in >> a.id;
        return in;
    }
};

int main()
{

    vector<typeA> v;
    int id = 1000;
    fstream file("testfile.txt", ios::in);
    typeA temp;
    while(file >> temp)
    {
        v.push_back(temp);
    }
    vector<typeA>::iterator iter;
    for(iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++)
    {
        cout << *iter;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) is perfect for this.

Comment: how did you write it?

Comment: When you read the second object, `getline()` gets a blank line left behind when you only read the `a.id` but not the newline that followed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `operator >>`. When you read `id`, the following newline character is not consumed, so when you read the next object you read an empty line as its name. One way to fix it is to call [in.ignore()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) after reading `id`:

```
friend istream& operator >>(istream& in, typeA& a)
{
    getline(in, a.name); // since the name is first and last i have to use getline
    in >> a.id;
    in.ignore();
    return in;
}
```

[Coliru demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b89d689a6c1e409d)

Comment: This worked. When i implement it into the homework some of the objects have multiple string members that i will need to used getline for, will i have to use in.ingore() after each one or just at the end.

Comment: @AndrewB. You have to use `ignore()` *before* `getline()`, if the previous read didn't consume newline, such as `operator>>` for standard types.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. if you have a 'getline()' after a cin you have to use 'ingore()'.